# font awesome icon without cdn - magento 2.0.8

Tags: fonts, magento2.0.8

I am looking to integrate font awesome icon into magento2. I have downloaded font-awesome version 4.6.3. The tree structure of the font-awesome folder is shown below.

[image: folder structure]

I referred to this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html) and got some idea about where to place fonts and CSS but I don't know where to place the remaining folder less and SCSS.

can anyone explain the step-by-step process of integrating font-awesome icons into Magento 2?

Comment: if you are including css file you don't need less, scss file, css file is enough. Let me know if you want to know how to include font-awesome.css file through xml.

Comment: please wait I will update my stuff in that question. I know how to include in xml.

Comment: yes you right it worked. no need  less and scss. thanks @ArunKarnawat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Steps to Integrate font awesome**

1. Download font-awesome library from this [link](http://fontawesome.io/)
2. place the font files in `<custom-theme-directory>/web/fonts`
3. place the css files in `<custom-theme-directory>/web/css`
4. Declare font awesome css in needed layout file

eg: Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <css src="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

5. we can call in phtml like `<i class="fa fa-binoculars"></i>`

Comment: This worked great! Curious.. What if any performance consequences are there from using a library like this?

Comment: I think the font path should be corrected to 
<custom-theme-directory>/web/webfonts