# How to add Fontawesome in Magento2 without CDN

Tags: magento2, javascript, less-css, font-awesome

I want to load Fontawesome in my Magento2 without CDN. I have downloaded the font awesome library from this link [Fontawesome 6.1.1](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.1/fontawesome-free-6.1.1-web.zip). And in zip file I got these files as shown in the figure [image: Font Awesome zip file]. And in my Magento2 folder at this path **C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\design\frontend\Hidden\apparel\web**
I have these files [image: files in web folder].

Please guide me where to add the font awesome files.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the related question link below:

[font awesome icon without cdn - magento 2.0.8](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136182/font-awesome-icon-without-cdn-magento-2-0-8)

But replace the font folder name from `<custom-theme-directory>/web/fonts`
to `<custom-theme-directory>/web/webfonts`.

If you are still stuck, feel free to comment here.

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved.
I added all the CSS files from fontawesome at this path **C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\design\frontend\Hidden\apparel\web\css**
And pasted webfonts folder at this path **C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\design\frontend\Hidden\apparel\web**.

And in **default.xml** I called it in this way `<css src="css/all.min.css" />` .

Thanks